# Polygon Layer Cleaning with QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, topology

I have a little situation with my data. I have vectorized a raster layer, and now I have some issues with the geometries, as you can see in the picture. Most of errors I have are like this one. Several polygons intersect themselves only in one point.

I identified them with Vector > Geometry Tools > Check geometry validity. How can I fix them automatically with QGIS?

[image: Most of errors I have are like this one. Several polygons that intersects themselves only in a node.]

Comment: Have you tried Vector > Geometry Tools > Check geometry validity?

Comment: These are known as 'hourglass' or 'bowtie' polygons, some self intersection is very common when downloading data or extracting from raster. Have a read of https://faunaliagis.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/bad-bad-polygon-fixing-invalid-geometries-with-quantum-gis/ and see if that helps. If you have access to Esri use Repair Geometry tool - works well and is very fast.

Comment: Hi Chris. Yes, that tool allowed me realize that I had these errors. It only indicates where is the problem but don't fix it :(

Comment: Hi Michael, unfortunately it wasn't helpful :( I'll try to see if I can reach that ArcGIS tool... Thank you!

Comment: I haven't tried this but perhaps using the _break_ option in the **v.clean** tool from GRASS might help. Here is a snippet of the description: "_The break tool breaks lines/boundaries at intersections and it also breaks lines/boundaries forming a collapsed loop_."

Comment: Thanks Joseph, but the result is the same.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that tool had no further means to correct the errors or a 'repair' counterpart. Or that you had run it. :) There are a few more suggested methods at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/