# Clip of polygons does not work properly by invalid geometry

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip

I want to clip a polygon shapefile by another polygon shapefile. Input polygon is the green one (first), clip polygon is the light blue one (second) and the result should look like the dark blue one (third). But the real result looks like the red one: there are some parts of the clip polygon which are missing (dark blue color under the red polygon). The projections are the same.

When I check the vector validity (Vector - Geometry Tools - Check geometry validity) for clip polygon, there appear 32 errors; probable cause of this wrong result.

I use QGIS version 2.14.2-Essen. What should I do to get the right result (dark blue one)?

[image: check geometry validity for input layers[![green layer - input, light blue - input clip, dark blue - desired output, red layer - real output layer]

Comment: Did you have also checking geometry validity for original shapefiles (input  and clip polygons)?

Comment: If you have installed **PostGis** perhaps solution of Luigi Pirelli in this answer can help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/fixing-geometry-validity-errors-in-qgis