# Cutting out polygon from other polygon / removing clip

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have a polygon that shows a lake. I have a second polygon that contains districts.

I want to cut out the lake so only get the bits of the districts that is on land. I tried clip, but I think I want an "anti-clip". What function can I use?

I used Difference, but it resulted in an error and I'm not sure it's the good function for this.

Comment: If you get an "invalid geometry" error, you'll need to [find and fix any geometry errors](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/fixing-geometry-validity-errors-in-qgis).

Comment: csk is right. Most of the time, it's because your geometries are invalids. The simplier, with QGIS 3.2 : Processing toolbox (Ctrl + Alt + T) -> Vector geometry -> Fix geometries.  2. Other reason may be that the two layers must have the same CRS (coordinate reference systeme)

Comment: this page could help : https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html?highlight=clip

Answer (score 1):

The Difference tool is what you want to use. The districts should be the input vector layer, and the lakes should be the difference layer. [This tutorial](http://blog.mastermaps.com/2013/06/splitting-and-clipping-shapefiles-with.html) walks through a very similar situation, clipping districts to match a coastline.

If you are still having errors please give explicit details (what are your inputs, what does the error text say, etc) so that community members are better able to help you.