# Extract a vector from a raster with a single boundary in QGIS

Tags: vector, vector-layer, raster-conversion, vectorization, boundaries

I have a "problem", I need transform a raster in a vector and it works but some pixels like the one in the print it is separated from the boundary, and for my use (a specific use of hypsometric curves) this cannot happen, I already tried to use 8 connectedness, but the error appears that the geometry of feature 0 is invalid. Is there any way for me to extract the limits of a raster and transform it into a vector, with a common limit?

[image]

Comment: There is no easy way to join that pixel to the rest of the pixels as a valid polygon, as two boundaries touch. You may be able to make the resulting polygon valid using `buffer(0)`

Comment: v.clean is suggested in the 2nd answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/fixing-geometry-validity-errors-in-qgis-2