# Broken shapefile

Tags: shapefile, corrupt

I have a shapefile that contains 907 features. All features are still visible in the attribute table and the fields contain the correct values. However, when opening it in QGIS it only draws 9 features. I have also tried to open it in ArcGIS and I get an error message: "There was a problem drawing the shapefile, drawing aborted"

I have tried to run the "check validity" for the geometries in QGIS but it crashes. However, when I run the "check geometry" tool in ArcGIS, the output is empty.

The file has: .shx, .shp, .dbf, .cpg, .shp.xml, .prj extensions. I have tried a number of times by deleting what are usually non mandatory files, but nothing changed.

I have also tried to export as a gdb, and also to copy the features to a new shapefile but nothing worked.

I don't know when and how the file got corrupted, but is there any way to recover it?

Comment: If the file is corrupt, it's corrupt. Recovery usually occurs from backup media. If you never made and validated a backup, it's time to do so for the next catastrophic loss.

Comment: See reference in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7809/fixing-corrupt-shapefile  worked for me. The one about shapechk.exe