# QGIS Vector Geometry Vanished

Tags: qgis, geometry, null, missing-data, archiving

I've been working on a project, in QGIS 3.16 Hannover (we started the project a while ago, in the Bonn version, but upgraded during the duration of project). Upon project completion we've been asked to hand over the shape files also, not just the layout pdfs.

As it turned out, the last version of the shp is missing geometry of most attributes. The attribute table contains up-to-date state, but most of features now have no geometry, i.e. they exist as entries in the attribute table, but have null geometry.

Does anybody have a solution? Is it possible that this situation arose, because me and my colleague worked on the same project, often simultaneously? I.e. could it have happened because we inadvertently wrote over same shapefiles at the same time?

Also, what is the latest on archiving QGIS projects? Is there an automatic function available?

I guess I'll live with the loss of data in this case, probably it'll take me a day to recover (that is draw missing geometries by hand).

Comment: QGIS Projects only contain links to spatial data, and information on how to display it - not the data itself. So yes, your (bad) practice of several people simultaneously working on the same data most likely broke it.

Comment: Well yeah, but ... what is the solution? How can I recover the data? Also, why have I lost the data, since the last version of the Qgis project worked perfectly, and neither me nor my colleague worked on the project since ?

Comment: Use standard Windows recovery methods. Can't answer the second question w/o knowing the project, the data, your data structure and its changes since the last time the shape file was intact.

Comment: I have seen shapes not draw but the data wasn't lost.  Run the check validity and/or fix geometries on your shapefile to be sure it isn't a simple geometry issue. Assuming data was lost, it could be a mismatch of your dbf records and your shp shapes which means you might be able to recover much of the work.  See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7809/fixing-corrupt-shapefile which includes trying the shapechecker utility.  Use copies.